# when i click the button it goes to back window in android

Tags: android

```
else if(view.getId()==equal){
        if (check_divide==true){
            outputScreen.setText("heyy");
        }
        else{
            outputScreen.setText("null");
        }
    }
```

here is the piece of code which runs fine when the if condition is true and it prints the "heyy" in the output secreen.
But whren i add

```
if (check_divide==true){
            Double result=x/y;
            outputScreen.setText(Double.toString(result));
        }
```

into the if conditon it goes to the back window look like as i have pressed the back button.

Comment: are you sure that it isn't crashing?

Comment: it might be crashing because y = 0

Comment: but it is not crashing

Comment: not assigning value 0 to y

Comment: Try changing Double to double. Double is a class, double is a primitive.

Comment: ^^autoboxing will be used

Comment: i have used double too

Comment: @Kistamushken when i just print the value of (y) it gives me the same error...

Comment: @StinePike i think here is no need of autoboxing.... when i just print the value of (y) it gives me the same error.